# Using execl to run a Linux command

Tags: c, linux, unix, exec

I need to list all files in the current directory which have a permission of 644 by writing a C language program.
I can not use `system()` and have to use `execl()` in order to use system calls.

This a line that I used in my code:

```
execl("/usr/bin/find", "find . -maxdepth 1 -perm 644", (char *)NULL);
```

The problem is that the code is searching the whole disk instead of the current directory.
Would you help me to fix it please?

---

```
        ...

        case 4:
            int status;
            switch (fork()){
                case -1: quit ("fork",1);
                case 0:
                execl("/usr/bin/find","find","." ,"-maxdepth" ,"1","-perm", "644",(char *)NULL) ;
                exit (200);
                default:
                wait(&status);
                exit(0);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Separate the arguments:

```
execl("/usr/bin/find", "find", ".", "-maxdepth", "1", "-perm", "644", (char *)NULL);
```

Your invocation was equivalent to invoking the `find` program with no arguments (and a very funny `argv[0]`).

Comment: I keep the line in a while loop and switch case but after listing the files script stops.

Comment: I'd need to see your code to understand what you mean.  Are you using `fork()` and `wait()` too?  Anything else?  Edit your question; don't try to put it in a comment.  And don't destroy the original question (and apologies if I'm telling you what you already know).

Comment: The problem is that when you use `execl()`, you replace the current process with a new one.  So, when you choose option 4, you replace your menu-driven program with `find`, and when the `find` stops, the real shell is back in business — your program committed suicide, if you like, when it replaced itself with `find`.  (It's a very morbid business, dealing with child processes that die on you.)  If you need to run the `find` command _and_ continue your program, use `fork()` and run `find` in the child and `wait()` for the child to complete in the parent.

Comment: And that is exactly the reason to avoid spawning with `fork()/execl()` if possible

Comment: You're re-revised code for 'case 4:' is almost correct; you just don't want to do `exit(0);` in the `default:` case (just `break`).  You want your program to continue.  (The `exit(200)` after the failed `execl()` is very important.)

Comment: it fixed. thank you for your help. I had to go through it. a newbie and lots of things to learn

Answer (score 2):

```
execl("/usr/bin/find","/usr/bin/find",  ".", "-maxdepth", "1", "-perm", "0644",(char *)NULL);
```

Answer (score 1):

For your particular task, using [file tree walk](http://linux.die.net/man/3/ftw) (`ftw`) is more appropriate.

ftw is just a library, so you don't need to spawn external process to get job done. Also, it is much easier to parse results.